# Wordpress updated from 4.1->4.7, got phpmailerException when resetting password

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer, updates, reset-password

We updated Wordpress from 4.1.something to 4.7.3. Everything works, except the mail that contains the new password when a user resets the password. The password is still reset, but no mail is obtained with the reset password, making it impossible to log in. As far as I know, this is the only mail that fails, registration mails and such still works.

There shouldn't be anything wrong with the code, it has worked for years. But something was clearly messed up when updating. When trying to send the mail, the following error occurs.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Invalid address:  (setFrom) service' in /var/www/site-adress/public_html/wp/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php:1023
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/site-adress/public_html/wp/wp-includes/pluggable.php(352): PHPMailer->setFrom('service', 'WordPress', false)
#1 /var/www/site-adress/public_html/wp-content/themes/site/functions.php(320): wp_mail('dummy.mail...', 'Site: passwor...', 'Your new passwo...', 'From: service')
#2 [internal function]: {closure}('')
#3 /var/www/site-adress/public_html/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#4 /var/www/site-adress/public_html/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
 #5 /var/www/site-adress/public_html/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#6 /var/www/site-adress/public_html/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(101): do_action in /var/www/site-adress/public_html/wp/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php on line 1023
```

Does anyone know how this should be solved? What does this information mean? Where does the problem lie?

Thank you, ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the email address for these emails by adding the following into your theme `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name' );
function new_mail_from( $old ) {
    return get_option( 'admin_email' );
}
function new_mail_from_name( $old ) {
    return get_option( 'blogname' ); 
}
```

Then, use `Settings > General` inside of WordPress to alter the email address and site name.

Thanks to PS below who clarifies: this code can be dropped into `functions.php` theme file AS IS without any modifications. You then use the WordPress admin interface to change the sending email address ("Email Address" field at the Settings > General page).

Comment: You're a lifesaver.

Comment: To clarify to any people with similar lack of skill or knowledge as myself who happen across this to potentially use it, no changes need to be make to Patrick's code. No replacing "new_mail_from" with actual emails or something. Just the code exactly as Patrick wrote it. I placed it right after the last function in the document and it worked, if that makes any difference. Thank you, once again. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer is saying that it can't send because the "from" address you asked it to use is invalid. It was set to `service`, which isn't going to go anywhere. You need to find where that address is set in your Wordpress config and update it to a proper email address, and then PHPMailer will be able to work.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. You're right in that I wasn't able to figure this out on my own. Thank you for making me aware of what the problem was, although I couldn't find a place to insert in the config-file to place the proper email address. I'll assume I need a to insert a new "define", so it's a google search away. Is there any advantages to doing that above doing it as Patrick suggested and override? Regardless, thank you very much for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable plugins for it to work

Comment: Please explain more in your answer or place it in comment